# How to find when two goals are achieved and return date?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have two list of numbers and a date field. I am trying to return the date when a condition for each field is met. I have List A that tracks X and is increasing every week and the goal is 30,868 and then List B tracks Y and is also increasing every week with a goal of 1,688,888. I would like to find a way to return the date that both conditions are satisfied. What is the way to go about doing this? I am able to do it individually for each using Index/Match, but is there a way to use it to return the date that both goals are met? I am using Excel 2010.

Formulas:

=INDEX($B$1:$B$288,MATCH(TRUE,$B1:$B$288>30868,0))

=INDEX($D$1:$D$288,MATCH(TRUE,$D1:$D$288>1688888,0))

[Lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARW4Z.png)

[Individual Formula/Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D6jk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that whenever one reaches the goal first it doesn't lose any could you not use what you have in terms of index/match and get the address of the corresponding date field and then the value of that.

Then just compare that with the other index/match.

If you post your existing formula then it'd be relatively easy for another user to then help you get the corresponding date.

Comment: Thanks for your help Tim, A quick fix was to just compare the dates using the MAX function and compare the dates.